# Unclear points in proof involving Jensen inequality

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, inequality, proof-explanation

Is "*the set $d_1\le|x-\mu|\le d_2$*" just another way of saying $\{x \in I:d_1\le|x-\mu|\le d_2\}$?

We have $d_2<d_1$. Doesn't this mean that this set is empty?

Why is the denominator bounded from below by $d_2^\alpha+d_2^n$? Don't we have $|x-\mu|^\alpha+|x-\mu|^n\ge d_1^\alpha+d_1^n$ because of $d_2<d_1$?

[image]

Comment: Yes we do have $|x-\mu|^\alpha+|x-\mu|^n\ge d_1^\alpha+d_1^n$, but we want to say: $(|x-\mu|^\alpha+|x-\mu|^n)^{-1}\ge d_2^\alpha+d_2^n$ (Really, the author should say the denominator is bounded above so the expression is bounded below).

Yes this is what the set $d_1 \leq |x-\mu| \leq d_2$ means.

Seems very likely that actually it is a typo and that $d_2 > d_1$, as this is consistent with the rest of the text.

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst Yes I was thinking about that too but at first we let $x \to \infty$ to find $d_1$ so $d_1$ is rather large. And then we let $x \to \mu$ so $d_2$ is rather small, i.e. $d_2<d_1$ but then our set would be empty as you said